# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

LINQ to EF:

```
 db.ReadonlyQuery<Transaction>()
     .Select(t => new ACurrentDayInfo
         {
              OrderId = t.TransactionIdentifier,
              OrderTime = t.TransactionTime,
              UserName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(t.UserInfo).RealName ?? ""
         })
     .ToListAsync();
```

The `t.UserInfo` is a json string like `{"RealName ":"XY"}` in each record of in table's field.
How can I translate this to a server query?

Comment: A workaround would be to call `ToList` before `Select` to execute the query on the client. Executing JsonConvert **within** the query isn't supported out-of-the-box, see linked question.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer if the Transaction has a lot of columns or contains a lot of data in that columns it may impact performance since it will translate into a select *

Comment: @PeterBons True, the best solution would be to store the data in a separate `UserInfo` table and build the JSON string on demand instead of saving the info as JSON and parsing it when the original data is needed. Btw: as far as I can see, all answers except yours would have the same or a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend you `ACurrentDayInfo` class with a getter like this

```
class  ACurrentDayInfo
{
    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(UserInfo).RealName ?? "";
        }
    }
}
```

and modify your query like this:

```
db.ReadonlyQuery<Transaction>()
                    .Select(t => new ACurrentDayInfo
                    {
                        OrderId = t.TransactionIdentifier,
                        OrderTime = t.TransactionTime,
                        UserInfo = t.UserInfo
                    }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: if " t.UserInfo"  has a lot of strings, the same time,I wanna to store the list to redis, it may impact performance??

Answer (score 0):

In EF Dbcontext don't support cast json in query, You need fix same that:

```
var listData = db.ReadonlyQuery<Transaction>()
                        .Select(t => new ACurrentDayInfo
                        {
                            OrderId = t.TransactionIdentifier,
                            OrderTime = t.TransactionTime,

                            UserInfo = t.UserInfo
                        }).ToListAsync();

foreach (var item in listData)
{
    item.UserName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(t.UserInfo).RealName ?? "" 
}
```